# infer typing for nested properties in generic

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have two issues. First of all; I want to convert the following structure:

```js
{ isElevated: { sm: true, xl: 'false' }, color: 'green' }
```

into the following

```js
{ isElevated: { _sm: true, _xl: 'false' }, color: 'green' }
```

So, I only want to prepend an underscore in keys of a nested object. I've created the following, but I have two issues:

1. In my current approach I loose typing when (re-)setting nested properties. How can I keep it?
2. Types of values are widened (`'green'` becomes `string`). I would like to keep the literal values without calling the arguments `as const`.

[Link to TS Playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgTgQwHYGcBmB7OBbACnDMFAHhgBooBpKCAD2AiQBMUoBrCEDNWKAXnadusAHz8oAbwBQUKAG0AagjgBLZMCgqkVALoAuWIuVqkwHTXqMWUDACMAVhADGwGbKgB+SW-fu5AOQgUBiZKTk1tDi4eGCNVdXMEVgADAH0AEglg1SQAcygAMh9fd0DgiFDOAF9k-UMleNMdAKCQsJAdAG5i2Srig1iGkzNuqu6pNABXJBcVDG1gRFRMHFIKajoGZlYo4RgRAAowAiIDCXl2iN0BuXbzKoBKb1kneeDBEFYBAHkHZ2AAHRRFBHE4oJ5JKhyLpSNxwCDASZwSKcFAA+FMSZOCAHA4IJxOChsJ58MTSXwqHgHUCQYTHQgoORscx8VlQABEdkcLnZT3JJQA9AKoABJADk2CgABsMCgtPkafKoAALCDwgEAnpQV6oDQANwQUvE9KITK6UCFUEhACVnFgmMRsvKKMgQCJuiVtW8NEhWhUAKKmVRBcS-bmAxiLFRBA4GqUPD0lHXvSPBr5QX3lJiBqNBAHYBBgXFMzgUOOTCA6EliORpTJRGplw0VqvjT3wxHIyRQDUA-GE+TMgxh-4AtAEbA5tMHVPR8FQMbFKo0KUoaD83wdpHac69-sUM0GE2M5kLxO9NxVCgSZeQ+DIdBYPBg0giBNSPpSZMaeEoSZSjQBEWB8VmwA5+RUFB-SlCADRCM4oBQbADEWCsKFoKUDHZNBDTXdkFzINxXhlOAsNyeFGHZQjHnGb9EKxbEUBQABGcRf3-QFIOg2CEBCOR2VSJD2RZNlUIgToLWFABxDAMCYWFLQACQwAB3bVkFFKBjlgyMoHLENxwwSUVJUJhGHlLwDhM4BlQwSYNCcQ0pSVazlSgZJIW-ZIHi-b0oBwlQpVYgR2IAgEuJguCKn4wTsGE-g2Rw1dxMkqAACEEHkuiAqlAAmNigg4gFiKwBKBHZDF2Qky0MvkoA)

```
type TransformProps<T, K extends keyof T = keyof T> = {
  [Variant in K]: T[Variant] extends object
    ? {
        [NestedKey in keyof T[Variant] as `_${string &
          NestedKey}`]: T[Variant][NestedKey];
      }
    : T[Variant];
};

function transform<T, K extends keyof T>(props: { [Key in K]: T[Key] }) {
  const keys = Object.keys(props) as K[];

  return keys.reduce((acc, k) => {
    if (typeof props[k] === "object") {
      // I'm losing typing here..
      const val = props[k]; // as Record<string, any>;
      const nestedEntries = Object.entries(val);
      const entries = nestedEntries.map(([key, value]) => [`_${key}`, value]);

      return { ...acc, [k]: Object.fromEntries(entries) };
    } else {
      return { ...acc, [k]: props[k] };
    }
  }, {} as TransformProps<T>);
}

const result = transform({
  isElevated: { sm: true, xl: "false" },
  color: "green",
});

const success1 = result.isElevated["_sm"] === true; // Good

// How can I prevent values from widening? (without calling with `as const`)
const fail1 = result.isElevated["_sm"] === false; // Bad
const fail2 = result.color === "red"; // Bad
```

Comment: The problem is not with the (type of the) `transform` function. It's the object literal itself whose type is automatically widened. The way to avoid that is to use `as const`. I don't understand why you don't want to use that.

Comment: @Bergi [`as const` not needed](https://tsplay.dev/m36akN)

Comment: @caTS Oh, interesting, but that doesn't help with something like `const arg = {…}; transform(arg);`, so I still would think that `as const` is the appropriate solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second problem is possible to solve. Your first however, is not really. It's very hard to do these kinds of manipulations while still keeping types accurate inside the implementation. You should probably just do a cast.

We'll use a very special type to remove the need for `as const`:

```
type Narrow<T> =
    | (T extends infer U ? U : never)
    | Extract<T, number | string | boolean | bigint | symbol | null | undefined | []>
    | ([T] extends [[]] ? [] : { [K in keyof T]: Narrow<T[K]> });
```

And use it here:

```
function transform<T, K extends keyof T>(props: { [Key in K]: Narrow<T[Key]> }) {
```

Now, everything works.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/m36akN)

Comment: I'm surprised declaring the parameter as `props: Narrow<{ [Key in K]: T[Key] }>` doesn't work :-(

Comment: Yeah, that's because it's no longer (or at least TypeScript doesn't know) an object type.

Comment: Thank you @caTS! Do you know why it is so hard (impossible?) to keep the types on these nested properties? Do you might have a direction I can look for to potentially solve this?

Comment: @wolvesback019 TypeScript always tries to infer the most general type for literals. We can tell TypeScript to be more specific with the Narrow type I have just shown. If this answers your question, consider upvoting or accepting it. If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Sorry, what I meant is that I now have to cast the nested properties (`props[k] as Record<>`) instead of TS inferring it. So TS is losing inference. But I can't seem to figure out why.

Comment: Unfortunately that's a limitation of TypeScript. Manipulations are pretty hard to type correctly in the implementation. Usually people resolve it with a cast. It should be no big deal.